# on hover - for a menuitem change background and textcolor

Tags: html, css, hover

I need some help please. I want to change in a menu item the background image and the color of the text on hover. Is there a way to do it only using css?

```
<div class="ItemContainer">
 <a class="menuItem" href="#">
   <span class="menuItemImage"></span>
   <span class="menuItemText">some Text</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have to assign hover property of css to your `menuItemText` and `menuItemImage`:

Here is an example for you to understand:

```css
.menuItemText,
.menuItemImage {
    padding:80px;
    border:1px solid;
    float: left;
}

.menuItemImage:hover,
.menuItemText:hover
{
    background-image: url('https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ItemContainer">
 <a class="menuItem" href="#">
   <span class="menuItemImage">some Image</span>
   <span class="menuItemText">some Text</span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me.
My problem is, I want to change the background-image AND the text-color on the same time.

Comment: but for both spans on hover of anyone of them

Comment: take a look at snippet now is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

**Changing the text colour:**

```
<script type="text/css">
.menuItemText:hover {
    color: #F00;
}
</script>
```

**Changing the background image:**

```
<script type="text/css">
.menuItemImage:hover {
    background-image: url('/path/to/image.png');
}
</script>
```